# Navigation Architecture Component - Dialog Fragments

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Is it possible to use the new Navigation Architecture Component with DialogFragment? Do I have to create a custom Navigator?

I would love to use them with the new features in my navigation graph.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, as of the `1.0.0-alpha01` build, there is no support for dialogs as part of your Navigation Graph. You should just continue to use [show()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment#show_4) to show a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Feature request for Navigation can be directed to the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=197448) - make sure to state your use case and why you'd find dialogs in your Navigation Graph useful.

Comment: Is there any update since the spring on the plan for dialogs?

Comment: @AdamHurwitz - feel free to star the [existing issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80267254) for updates.

Comment: Accepted answer is no longer valid as `DialogFragment` is now supported with `2.1.0-alpha03` version

Comment: You just need change your DialogFragment in NavGraph as Razor's answer below!

Comment: Diaglog destinations are now supported and available in navigation ui component

Answer (score 91):

**May 2019 Update**:

> DialogFragment are now fully supported starting from `Navigation 2.1.0`, you can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0) and [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-create-destinations#create-dialog)

**Old Answer for Navigation <= 2.1.0-alpha02:**

I proceeded in this way:

**1)** Update `Navigation` library at least to version `2.1.0-alpha01` and copy both files of this [modified gist](https://gist.github.com/matpag/74ce059d590ff571c8240428b274c8c5) in your project.

**2)** Then in your navigation host fragment, change the `name` parameter to your custom `NavHostFragment`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.app.navigation.MyNavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />
```

**3)** Create your `DialogFragment` subclasses and add them to your `nav_graph.xml` with:

```
<dialog
    android:id="@+id/my_dialog"
    android:name="com.example.ui.MyDialogFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/my_dialog" />
```

**4)** Now launch them from fragments or activity with

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.my_dialog)
```

or similar methods.

Comment: I have tried with last version and it is working but animations are not running for me. I have to set them in dialog class. Is this happening to someone too?

Comment: How to handle its Positive & negative click listener.

Comment: @Pinakin you handle results directly in your custom `DialogFragment`, for example using the `onCreateDialog` and setting a `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton` listeners

Comment: can I implement that for TimePickerFragment?

Comment: @Pinakin if you are using navigation to go to a dialog fragment, think of it like navigating to any other fragment. How would you get a result back from navigating to a regular fragment? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between If the dialog is "owned" by the fragment that started it and you want click listeners you may be better off using a `Dialog` and skipping navigation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible, You can access view of parent fragment from dialog fragment by calling `getParentFragment().getView()`. And use the view for navigation.

Here is the example

```
Navigation.findNavController(getParentFragment().getView()).navigate(R.id.nextfragment);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**. The framework is made in such a way that you can create a class extending the `Navigator` abstract class for the views that does not come out-of-the box and add it to your `NavController` with the method `getNavigatorProvider().addNavigator(Navigator navigator)`

If you are using the `NavHostFragment`, you will also need to extend it to add the custom Navigator or just create your own `MyFragment` implementing `NavHost` interface. It's so flexible that you can create your own xml parameters with custom attrs defined in `values`, like you do creating custom views. Something like this (not tested):

```
@Navigator.Name("dialog-fragment")
class DialogFragmentNavigator(
        val context: Context,
        private val fragmentManager: FragmentManager
) : Navigator<DialogFragmentNavigator.Destination>() {

    override fun navigate(destination: Destination, args: Bundle?,
                          navOptions: NavOptions?, navigatorExtras: Extras?
    ): NavDestination {
        val fragment = Class.forName(destination.name).newInstance() as DialogFragment
        fragment.show(fragmentManager, destination.id.toString())
        return destination
    }

    override fun createDestination(): Destination = Destination(this)

    override fun popBackStack() = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()

    class Destination(navigator: DialogFragmentNavigator) : NavDestination(navigator) {

        // The value of <dialog-fragment app:name="com.example.MyFragmentDialog"/>
        lateinit var name: String

        override fun onInflate(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) {
            super.onInflate(context, attrs)
            val a = context.resources.obtainAttributes(
                    attrs, R.styleable.FragmentNavigator
            )
            name = a.getString(R.styleable.FragmentNavigator_android_name)
                    ?: throw RuntimeException("Error while inflating XML. " +
                            "`name` attribute is required")
            a.recycle()
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

my_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_assistant"
        android:name="com.example.ui.HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_to_dialog"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_dialog" />
    </fragment>

    <dialog-fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dialog"
        android:name="com.example.ui.MyDialogFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/my_dialog" />

</navigation>
```

The fragment that will navigate.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), NavHost {

    private val navControllerInternal: NavController by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE){
        NavController(context!!)
    }

    override fun getNavController(): NavController = navControllerInternal

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Built-in navigator for `fragment` XML tag
        navControllerInternal.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(
            FragmentNavigator(context!!, childFragmentManager, this.id)
        )
        // Your custom navigator for `dialog-fragment` XML tag
        navControllerInternal.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(
            DialogFragmentNavigator(context!!, childFragmentManager)
        )
        navControllerInternal.setGraph(R.navigation.my_navigation)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, 
                              container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home)
        view.id = this.id

        view.button.setOnClickListener{
            getNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_to_dialog)
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I created custom navigator for DialogFragment.

Sample is [here](https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/navigation-dialog-sample).
(It's just sample, so it might be any problem.)

```
@Navigator.Name("dialog_fragment")
class DialogNavigator(
    private val fragmentManager: FragmentManager
) : Navigator<DialogNavigator.Destination>() {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "dialog"
    }

    override fun navigate(destination: Destination, args: Bundle?, 
            navOptions: NavOptions?, navigatorExtras: Extras?) {
        val fragment = destination.createFragment(args)
       fragment.setTargetFragment(fragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment, 
               SimpleDialogArgs.fromBundle(args).requestCode)
        fragment.show(fragmentManager, TAG)
        dispatchOnNavigatorNavigated(destination.id, BACK_STACK_UNCHANGED)
    }

    override fun createDestination(): Destination {
        return Destination(this)
    }

    override fun popBackStack(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    class Destination(
            navigator: Navigator<out NavDestination>
    ) : NavDestination(navigator) {

        private var fragmentClass: Class<out DialogFragment>? = null

        override fun onInflate(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) {
            super.onInflate(context, attrs)
            val a = context.resources.obtainAttributes(attrs,
                    R.styleable.FragmentNavigator)
            a.getString(R.styleable.FragmentNavigator_android_name)
                    ?.let { className ->
                fragmentClass = parseClassFromName(context, className, 
                        DialogFragment::class.java)
            }
            a.recycle()
        }

        fun createFragment(args: Bundle?): DialogFragment {
            val fragment = fragmentClass?.newInstance()
                ?: throw IllegalStateException("fragment class not set")
            args?.let {
                fragment.arguments = it
            }
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While the library is in alpha it is changing like crazy. This implementation does not work anymore in alpha11.

Answer (score 1):

[Version 2.1.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0-alpha03) was Released so we can finally use DialogFragments. Unfortunately for me, I have some issues with the backstack when using cancelable dialogs. Probably I have a faulty implementation of my dialogs..

[LATER-EDIT] My implementation was good, the problem is related to  Wrong dialog counting for DialogFragmentNavigator as is described in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132495830)
As a workaround you can have a look [on my recommendation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132495830#comment3)

Comment: I ran into this problem as well. Just a single test would have been enough to find this issue, yet they released a new version of the library that doesn't even work because they couldn't bother to test it. Makes you wonder what their quality process is like.

Answer (score 0):

Updated for:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.0-rc04"
```

And use  in my_nav_graph.xml

```
<dialog
android:id="@+id/my_dialog"
android:name="com.example.ui.MyDialogFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/my_dialog" />
```

Comment: This is the updated and correct solution! Works for me!

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to just use a regular fragment and make it look similar to a dialog. I found it was not worth the hassle so I used the standard way using show(). If you insist [See here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6014-the-navigation-architecture-component-tutorial-getting-started) for a way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It is possible now. In it's initial release it wasn't possible but now
from "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0-alpha03" this navigation version you can use dialog fragment in navigation component.

Check this out:- [Naviagtion dialog fragment support](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation)