# Android NavController with <dialog> flashes before navigating

Tags: android, android-navigation

I have a navigation graph that looks like this:

Fragment 1 --> (Action A) --> DialogFragment 1 --> (Action B) --> Fragment 2

When performing Action B, we unfortunately don't switch directly directly to Fragment 2. Instead, the screen first shows Fragment 1 for a short moment (0.1 seconds or so), which looks very bad for my flow.

I'm using the  feature as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55256858/3375649), with [navigation-fragment version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.navigation/navigation-fragment) 2.1.0-rc01, which is the most stable version currently available with the `<dialog>` feature.

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Override the `dismiss()` function of your `DialogFragment`:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        getView().post(() -> super.dismiss());
    }
}
```

This is just a patch until the feature will be fixed, it works for me, please update especially if it doesn't work for you.

The problem is some race between:

1. The fragment transaction to Fragment 2 (which is correctly called first in `Navigation.java`, see `NavDestination newDest = navigator.navigate(...`, but probably takes a moment in the looper queue before being executed )

And

2. The Dialog `dismiss()` (which is correctly called only afterwards, but happens first)