# Dialog Fragment Using Navigation Components

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to show dialog using navigation component in android. I have gone through the other question asked at stackoverflow [Navigation Architecture Component - Dialog Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311637/navigation-architecture-component-dialog-fragments)

I have added dialog component in `nav_graph.xml` as below

```
 <dialog
    android:id="@+id/dialog"
    android:name="com.android.example.ui.MyDialogFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/dialog_fragment" />
```

I have added an action in my other fragment to show the dialog as below in `nav_graph.xml`

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/Fragment1"
        android:name="com.android.example.ui.Fragment1"
        android:label="Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_dialog"
            app:destination="@id/dialog" />
</fragment>
```

I have created a `kotlin` class `MyDialogFragment` as below

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.dialog_fragment,
            container, false
        )
    }
}
```

Here from `Fragment1` class, I am trying to show dialog as below

```
 findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_dialog)
```

when I try to show the dialog, I get the below error

**Preblem 1 is Solved**

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.navigation.fragment.DialogFragmentNavigator$Destination cannot be cast to androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator$Destination
    at com.android.dairy.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onDestinationChanged(MainActivity.kt:47)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.dispatchOnDestinationChanged(NavController.java:504)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1142)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:944)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:877)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:863)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:851)
```

**Problem2**

How can I get the instance of MyDialogFragment to update its properties or setup the button `onClick` listener in `Fragment1`

Comment: Please include the full stack trace for your exception. Did you read the [guide for returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result) and specifically the [Considerations when using dialog destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#additional_considerations)?

Comment: my use case is different. First thing is when I try to navigate to dialog without any result then The above exception is coming. I am updating the full stack trace

Comment: The exception is coming from **your** `onDestinationChanged` callback from your `MainActivity`. Please include that code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes the issue was in my activity where I was casting the fragment destination. So problem 1 is solved. is there a way to get the instance of dialog fragment in the host fragment?

Comment: So...did you read the guide on returning a result? That's how you're supposed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem says:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.navigation.fragment.DialogFragmentNavigator$Destination
    cannot be cast to androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator$Destination
at com.android.dairy.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onDestinationChanged(MainActivity.kt:47)
```

So your issue is that your `onDestinationChanged` callback in your `MainActivity` is incorrectly casting your type of destination. You need to change your code to avoid that.

Your second problem is about returning a result from your dialog. The documentation covers [returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result) and even has a section specifically around [Additional considerations when using DialogFragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#additional_considerations) (namely, that the `Fragment`'s Lifecycle isn't affected by a dialog, so this is one case where using the `NavBackStackEntry`'s Lifecycle can specifically help you).